# How to access an HTML attribute and retrieve data from it in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, dom

I'm new to PHP and I would like to know how to retrieve data from an HTML element such as an `src`?

It's very easy to do that in jQuery:

```
$('img').attr('src');
```

But I have no idea how to do it in PHP (if it is possible).

Here's an example I'm working on:

1. I loaded `$result` into SimpleXMLElement and stored it into `$xml`:

   `$xml = simplexml_load_string($result) or die("Error: Cannot create object");`
2. Then used `foreach` to loop over all elements:

   ```
   foreach($xml->links->link as $link){
       echo 'Image: ' . $link->{'link-code-html'}[0] . '</br>'; 
       // returns sometihing similar to: <a href='....'><img src='....'></a>
   }
   ```
3. Inside of the `foreach` I'm trying to access links (`src`) in `img`.

Is there a way to access `src` of the `img` nested inside of the `a` — clear when outputted to the screen:

```
    echo 'Image: ' . $link->{'link-code-html'}[0] . '</br>';
```

Comment: Please dont summarise your code. Show all the RELEVANT code and remember to explain the data you are processing as well, with at least an example

Comment: Well, this is all I have to share. And btw the point is already in my code, I only forgot it by mistake when I was typing here. The output is an HTML: an `img` inside of an `a`. It's easy to retrieve the attribute in jQuery, but I have no idea how to do it in PHP (if possible). And this is my question.

Comment: Then instead of echoing that straight out to the browser, put it in a variable and then you will have to do some text processing on that variable to acces/manipulate the info in those attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with the built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) APIs, and then you can use the [`getAttribute`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) method on any matching `img` node:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// Load some example HTML. If you need to load from file, use ->loadHTMLFile
$doc->loadHTML("<a href='abc.com'><img src='ping1.png'></a>
                <a href='def.com'><img src='ping2.png'></a>
                <a href='ghi.com'>something else</a>");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
// Collect the images that are children of anchor elements
$imgs = $xpath->query("//a/img");

foreach($imgs as $img) {
    echo "Image: " . $img->getAttribute("src") . "\n";
}
```

Comment: It works! I've been looking for this. Simple, Clean & Easy. +5